# Python: How to loop through a list to find the maximum value with a positive value indexed in another list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists. I'd like to find the largest value in `list_one` that, when using the same index in `list_two`, has a positive value. I do not want to sort the lists as the indices must maintain their integrity. See example below (my real life problem has hundreds of items per list so a loop must be used):

```
list_one = [12, 300, 47, 977, 200]
list_two = [-8, 10, 2, -1, 4]
```

The max value in `list_one` is `977`, which is index `[3]`. But if we look at the same index in `list_two` we see it has a negative value. The next highest value is 300, and that index does have a positive value in list two. So the desired outcome of this algorithm would return an index of `1`.  Here is what I have so far:

```
max_value = 0
max_index = 0
counter = 0

for value in list_one:
    if value > max_value:
       max_value = value
       max_index = counter
    counter = counter + 1

if list_two[max_index] > 0:
    return max_index
else:
    # Code needed to find 2nd largest value in list one, and so on...
```

Comment: Python indexes start at zero. So the value of `300` is at index `1`.

Comment: Yes, that is how my question is written I believe? 300 is at index 1, which makes it the highest value in ```list_one``` with a positive value in the same index in ```list_two```

Comment: Just multiply two list and sort it.

Comment: Yes, @FinDev, I misread, sorry.

Comment: @Canasta I do not want to sort the lists as the indices must maintain their integrity, I've updated the question with this stipulation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the max of `enumerate(list_one)` with a key that tests of `list_two`'s value is positive

```
list_one = [12, 300, 47, 977, 200]
list_two = [-1, 1, 1, -1, 1]

max(enumerate(list_one), key=lambda t: (list_two[t[0]] > 0, t[1]))
```

This will return: `(1, 300)`, giving both the index and value you are are looking for.

Given a different list you will see a consistent result:

```
list_one = [12, 300, 47, 977, 500]
list_two = [-1, 1, 1, -1, 1]

max(enumerate(list_one), key=lambda t: (list_two[t[0]] > 0, t[1]))
# (4, 500)
```

Comment: I was going to try and use `zip` for this, but this seems a better solution.

Comment: @Mark Meyer thank you for the solution! I am attempting to implement now, and will accept once I've got it working